# Simultaniously scroll 2 JTables?

Tags: java, scroll, jtable

I am trying to scroll two Jtables at the same time. Each JTable is placed on a JScrollpane and both JScrollpanes are set on a JSplitpane. Here the relöevant code for scrolling:

```
teststepScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        rerouteScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        teststepScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setModel(
                rerouteScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().getModel());

........

public void setTeststepTableFocus(final int teststep) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (teststep <= teststepTable.getModel().getRowCount() - 1){
                    teststepTable.setRowSelectionInterval(teststep, teststep);
                    teststepTable.scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle(teststepTable.getCellRect(teststep, 0, true)));
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Sadly it does not work at all. Any ideas? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is what I would do:**

Step 1: Access the scrollbars of the panels:

> ```
> JScrollBar verticalBar1 = teststepScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
> JScrollBar verticalBar2 = rerouteScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
> ```

Step 2: Add [AdjustmentListeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/AdjustmentListener.html) to both ScrollBars:

```
verticalBar1.addAdjustmentListener(
    new AdjustmentListener(){
    void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e){
         //Change the scrollposition of the other bar here using the values
         from the adjustmentEvent 
    }
});
```

Do the same for the second scrollbar but change the scroll position of the first scrollbar.

What this basically does is that you add listeners to your scrollbars. Whenever you scroll through them, you receive an [AdjustementEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/AdjustmentEvent.html) that tells you whether the scroll value got incremented or decremented.

This is just a general idea to tackle the problem. Unfortunately I can't write real and working code at the moment. I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

What I have did, to scroll the two table simultaneously is, I am just managing their `selectionModel`. So when you select any row from first table the same row index is selected in second table.

Suppose there are two tables like `table` and `table1`. First table (`table`) is placed on first `scrollPane` called `scroll` and second table (`table1`) placed on second `scrollPane` called `scroll1`.

Just set the second table's `selectionModel` to first table's `selectionModel` and same for `scrollPane` as:

```
table.setSelectionModel(table1.getSelectionModel());
scroll.getVerticalScrollBar().setModel(scroll1.getVerticalScrollBar().getModel());
```

---

**Useful Link**

[How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)